# ORA-21780: Maximum number of object durations exceeded

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

When I tried to update a table which contain 488000 records I got  "ORA-21780: Maximum number of object durations exceeded" Error.Please advise me how to resolve this error.

```
  SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE UNLIMITED
  DECLARE
     v_temp NUMBER :=0;
     v_id NUMBER :=0;
  BEGIN

     FOR fs  IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE date < '01-NOV-15')
     LOOP
         v_temp := (fs.DEPARTURE - fs.ARRIVAL);
         v_id :=fs.id;

         UPDATE flown_sectors SET DEPARTURE = v_temp 
         WHERE id = v_id; 

     END LOOP;

     EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 
         dbms_output.put_line('EXCEPTION AT ' ||v_id );
  END;
```

**Error report:**

```
ORA-21780: Maximum number of object durations exceeded.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 69
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 82
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 112
ORA-06512: at line 17

*Cause: This typically happens if there is infinite recursion in the PL/SQL function that is being executed.

*Action: User should alter the recursion condition in order to prevent infinite recursion.
```

Comment: The comment and the error don't appear to have anything to do with each other.  It doesn't appear that you're using an object type at all.  Are you certain that this is the code that is throwing that error?  What line throws the error?

Comment: Error report -

ORA-21780: Maximum number of object durations exceeded.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 69
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 82
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 112
ORA-06512: at line 17
ORA-21780: Maximum number of object durations exceeded.
21780. 00000 -  "Maximum number of object durations exceeded."
*Cause:    This typically happens if there is infinite recursion in the PL/SQL
           function that is being executed.
*Action:   User should alter the recursion condition in order to prevent
           infinite recursion.

Comment: Any triggers on `flow_sectors` table ?

Comment: In the code you posted, you have only one call to `dbms_output` and that's in an exception handler that can be called at most once.  Are you actually calling `dbms_output` inside a loop that is supposed to execute half a million times??

Comment: If this is your real code you should update the whole batch with a single sql `update`- statement instead of looping every single line.

Comment: No, I didn't use exception handler inside the loop.

Comment: It is a bad design to loop through all the rows to do an UPDATE. **row-by-row processing is slow-by-slow**. Avoid the loops, and don't do it in PL/SQL.

You could do it in pure SQL using a MERGE statement.

`MERGE INTO flown_sectors fs
USING (SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE DATE < DATE '2015-11-01') d
ON(fs.ID = d.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET fs.departure = d.departure - d.drrival;`

Comment: Also, 
    `WHERE date < '01-NOV-15'`

'01-NOV-15' is NOT a DATE, it is a string. You are comparing a date with a string. You should use TO_DATE to explicitly convert a literal into date. If you are not concerned with the time portion, better use ANSI Date literal which uses a fixed format 'YYYY-MM-DD' and therefore is NLS independent.

`WHERE DATE < DATE '2015-11-01'`

Comment: @LalitKumarB, the interesting part here is the actual question. When you count up to the line number from the exception backtrace, you'll understand that the exception occured in `dbms_output.put_line()` proc. Why's that? Now that's a mystery to solve! :-)

Comment: @nop77svk That's not interesting because it is quite obvious that the line number in the error stack would be incorrect due to `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN` handler. It is itself a bug when using it without an immediate **RAISE**. Count properly, and you will find that `Line 17` is nothing but the `EXCEPTION block`. So, the line number that you see is not the actual error line, but the handle is moved to exception block. and there is no RAISE to re-raise the error and give handle back to caller. Read [**WHEN OTHERS - A bug**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2014/05/02/when-others-then-null-a-bug/)

Comment: @LalitKumarB, OK, it appears that you're absolutely certain about what you're talking about. Then I have no more to say. :-D

Comment: @nop77svk Probably you were not aware of this, you could test it and see. And this is a FAQ(frequently asked question) in PL/SQL. Might be interesting for you to read http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/WHEN_OTHERS , http://lalitkumarb.com/2014/05/02/when-others-then-null-a-bug/ and of course by the master T.Kyte https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1155066278457 :-)

Comment: Probably **you** are not aware of this, but it does not matter what your or Tom's opinion is on the use of the `when others then ...` without re-raising an exception! That's not the interesting part about this question. And as for your blog - I don't read beginners' opinions. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

As per the code in the question, if you go on insisting for PLSQL method, try for BULK Update rather than ROW_BY_ROW Update. A very simple scenario mentioned below to suffice your problem. Let me know if this helps.

```
DECLARE
TYPE lv
IS OBJECT
(EMPNO EMP.EMPNO%TYPE,
SAL EMP.SAL%TYPE
);
TYPE lv_tab IS TABLE OF lv
INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
lv_tab_emp lv_tab;
BEGIN
  SELECT empno,sal BULK COLLECT INTO lv_tab_emp FROM emp;
  FORALL I IN lv_tab_emp.FIRST..lv_tab_emp.LAST
  UPDATE EMP_V1 
  SET SAL = 5100
  WHERE EMPNO = lv_tab_emp(i).empno;
  END IF;
END;
```